# Getting available RAM in OS/400 with C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, memory, ibm-midrange

I need to determine the available RAM on several platforms in C or C++.

I've found some cross-platform code for this here:
https://www.opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-84/sort/physmem.c

One of the target platforms for my project is OS/400.
Will the code I linked above return actual available RAM on OS/400?
If not, how can I obtain available RAM on OS/400?

In the short term, I think I'm limited to using either C++98 or C++03, because the Windows project is currently maintained in Visual Studio 2003. I don't know what compilers are being used on other platforms.

**Edit: some background...**
I'm working on software that my employer developed about 10 years ago, but which I had nothing to do with until a few months ago.
It uses a database stored as a single file with an in-house format divided into many pages of a fixed size.
The current behaviour on all platforms (Windows, Linux, Solaris, and OS/400 that I know of) is to load pages into memory (in the form of char-arrays) as needed, up to a maximum of 64 MB. The total data size is about 1.1 GB.
Testing on Windows, Linux and Solaris shows a large performance gain by increasing the 64 MB limit.

Considering the comments, especially that of Whozcraig, what would be appropriate behaviour on OS/400?
Would it work to just have no limit to how much "memory" is used?
There's nowhere near enough time to create a significantly different data structure and behaviour for one little-used platform.

Comment: If the OS has a way to see how much memory is available you could find that value using a memory-viewer on whatever application that shows it and use that address to get the memory available value. Yes this is hackery and that address can change at any time when the OS receives patches so it will not be a stable fix.

Comment: I always thought that the whole idea of OS/400 was to prevent people from messing with such details as "available RAM". :)

Comment: @oakad - I have no idea if that's the case. I know very little about the OS or the hardware it runs on. I'm just trying to make some old software run faster by automatically using more memory if it's available.

Comment: @ScottLeis with few exceptions (*very few, in fact*) OS/400 is one platform you *don't* want to make memory-decisions like this,and in fact, most of the self-caching algorithms people use, load that file into "memory" etc, are actually self-defeating. OS/400 is unlike most OS's you'll ever experience. Its massive linear address space encompasses *the universe*, and it is designed from the hardware up to make intelligent decisions about resource management like memory utilization, so you don't have to.

Comment: @WhozCraig - Very interesting. Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: I believe it depends on the [LPAR](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg246251.html) configuration; do you want physical or logical? And even more importantly, what do you intend to do with this information? Bump it up to 128 MB (or 256 MB) and test it (and perhaps implement a back down strategy on `malloc` fail).

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have pointed out, the approach you are taking to your underlying problem (in the background section) is questionable for this particular platform. However, putting that aside, and just focusing on your initial question on how to determine how much RAM is available, the answer is as follows:

To find out the RAM available to the LPAR on which you are running, you can call the [`dlpar_get_info`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/apis/dlpar_get_info.htm) API. You need to `#include <qpmlpmgt.h>`, and then do something like this:

```
dlpar_info_format1_t info1;
int rc = dlpar_get_info(&info1, dlpar_info_format1_ID, sizeof(dlpar_info_format1_t));
if (rc < 0) { /* Handle error */ }
else {
  printf("Maximum Memory (MB): %llu\n", info1.max_memory);
  printf("Minimum Memory (MB): %llu\n", info1.min_memory);
  printf("Memory Increment (MB): %llu\n", info1.memory_region);
  printf("Defined Memory (MB): %llu\n", info1.def_mem);
}
```

Note this API is new in V5R3.

Comment: I've given an upvote for the information, but I'm unlikely to mark this as an answer because I have no ability to test (no access to any OS/400 or similar systems), and am no longer working on this project. Thanks anyway.